ASP.NET MVC add headers and redirect to an external url
I need to write an small ASP.NET MVC website which sole purpose is to capture headers sent from a legacy website, add these headers to a request and redirect to a Blazor server app (including headers).
How can I add headers to a request and redirect to an external URL in a controller action?
I've tried HttpClient, WebClient and HttpWebRequest but none support redirecting.
I also tried:
Response.Headers.Add("Test", "Test redirect");
Response.Redirect("https://mywebsite.com/", true);

The redirection works but the header is not added.

Mmm perhaps you can create a new response with the status code 30X , i can check if it will work, haven't my dev computer at hand

"capture headers and redirect" sounds like a reverse proxy - might take a look at YARP https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/

Can you double check your tags. Blazor requires at a minimum ASP.NET Core 3.1.

You cannot do that, because 302 redirect are handled by browser and it will not re-attach headers, refer to this answer.
So you can try to create a new response which you need to manually manage all response details, including status codes, redirect URLs, and all custom headers.
example:
Response.StatusCode = 302;

Response.Headers.Add("Location", "https://mywebsite.com/");

Response.Headers.Add("Test", "Test redirect");
Response.Headers.Add("AnotherHeader", "AnotherValue");
...

